# 3blue1brown's Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey I was going through 3blue1brown's video about linear transformation in space(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&index=3&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab at 4:00) and was wondering how the unit vectors get transformed such that the component in which they were 0 is now non-zero.

Eg) in the video vector [1,0] becomes [3,-2]

This matrix is adding a y component to the unit vector but how is it giving it a direction that our original never had?

I was curious how unit vector in x direction now gets a y component:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\          
    \end{pmatrix} [1,0]'= $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
a + 0b \\
c + 0d \\          
\end{pmatrix}$$=
\begin{pmatrix}
a  \\
c  \\          
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
$$

This seems a bit strange to me as the x-component is added c times and made into the y-component.

side question: the matrix [[3,0],[-2,0]] transforms [0,0] to [0,0] and [0,1] or any [0,a] to [0,0] therefore points in this new space are not unique. This is not consistent with the stretching of the axis metaphor in the video right as this collapses a the line [0,a] to [0,0]?

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 \\          
\end{pmatrix} [0,a]'=[0,0]
$$

Comment: What do you mean "the points are not unique"?  Which two points do you think are the same?  It is true that some transformations send two points to the same point, but that is nothing to be surprised by...

Comment: And how do you get blue2brown from 3blue1brown?

Comment: Please also take a look at our basic [formatting tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  When people encountered a question that lacks simple formatting (you didn't even use a single line break) and seems to have so many mistakes, they can be less inclined to answer.

Comment: made the changes :)

Comment: Some linear transformations are invertible; some aren't.

Comment: I don't understand what is the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This matrix is adding a $y$ component to the unit vector but how is it giving it a direction that our original never had?

This seems to indicate that you expect vectors cannot change direction under a linear transformation. But this happens all the time: for example, rotations are linear transformations, and most rotations *do* change the directions of vectors. For example, in $\mathbb R^3$ or $\mathbb R^2$, you can take any two nonzero vectors and line them up to point in the same direction using a rotation.

Vectors that a linear transformation only scales, and doesn't change the direction of, are special: they're called *eigenvectors* for that transformation.  Sometimes a transformation doesn't have *any* eigenvectors (for example, a 90 degree rotation in the plane.)  I haven't watched the video link yet, but if it is discussing a transformation stretching certain vectors, it is almost certainly talking about an eigenvector (although it may be hidden in the context.)

> therefore points in this new space are not unique.

The linear transformations that map the points uniquely are called *nonsingular* and again, that's a special property that not all linear transformations have.

Comment: My confusion was the term "linear" implies a scalar times your vector. So a*(1,0) will never have a y component. However here we are somehow getting a y-component through the matrix which no 'linear' combination can get. Can you speak about how in this linearity this is fine.

Comment: @Rahul Deora, linear does not imply scalar times vector, where did you get that from?

Comment: Then what does 'linear' imply?

Comment: @Rahul, $A(\alpha \vec v+\beta\vec w) = \alpha A\vec v+\beta A\vec w.$ It even shows you that property in the video, right past 4:00 where you wanted us to look (4:28, to be more precise).

Comment: @RahulDeora perhaps you should rewatch the video from the start, or watch a separate video on the same topic.

Comment: @rschwieb yes the change in direction part that you spoke about. Look at the animation at 9:08. One basis is changed and then the other can be changed in any way regardless of the first. Isn't this problematic as the spacing of the first would be affected as that is also acting in y direction?

Comment: @RahulDeora What do you mean "spacing"?  Are you talking about the property of linear maps sending parallel lines to parallel lines?  Sorry, I won't have a lot of time to watch the video soon. I'm just working from basic principles.  I can't exactly grasp what you're implying with your verbal description. Perhaps you can come up with a simple toy numerical example about something happening that you don't like?